# MongoDB Aggregate function in Node timing out/not returning value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to query a mongoDB collection so that I can return the sum of each suppliers total amount invoiced, using the mongoshell i can get the aggregate function working using

```
db.invoice.aggregate ([
    {$group: {_id: "$supplier_name",
      total: {$sum: "$invoice_amount"} } }
    ])
```

in the backend of my application i have a routes folder set up, here I can succesfully query my db with things such as

```
invoiceRoute.route('/supplier-count').get((req, res) => {
  Invoice.count({supplier_name: 'xyx'}, (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    return next(error)
  } else {
    res.json(data);
  }
  })})
```

However when i try run this code I am using for the aggregate function doesn't return anything

```
invoiceRoute.route('/generate-report').get((res) => {
    Invoice.aggregate ([
        {$group: 
            {_id: "$supplier_name", 
             total: {$sum: "$invoice_amount"}} }
            ]), (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            return next(error)  
            } else {
            res.json(data);
      }}});
```

I've tried using the .toArray function as suggested in other answers but it responds with

```
Invoice.aggregate(...).toArray is not a function
```

I've checked the requests using postman and it times out before receiving a response however other requests do return responses.

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: `.toArray()` is a node native driver of mongodb function & It seems you are using `Mongoose`. don't use that.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `req` and `next` in your route function: `invoiceRoute.route('/generate-report').get((res) => {`

```
invoiceRoute.route('/generate-report').get((req, res, next) => {
    Invoice.aggregate([{
        $group: {
            _id: "$supplier_name",
            total: {
                $sum: "$invoice_amount"
            }
        }
    }]), (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            return next(error)
        }

        res.json(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried this & still it doesn't return anything

Comment: Can you log values returned from aggregation query before if block starts, e.g. `console.log(error, data)` and also before aggregation query starts to ensure if route `get` `/generate-report` is called

Comment: Got it working, I was missing the req, and next in my route function but also turns out i misplaced a parenthesis after the array, which was stopping the res being called.